# Kafka consumer offset not getting resettled to 0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Whenever I am trying to reset the offset of my kafka consumer group I am getting an error-

WARN New offset (0) is lower than earliest offset for topic partition

Comment: Kafka offsets keep growing whilst messages are only retained based on a limit so setting to 0 may result in this.  Why not use 'earliest' instead of 0?

Comment: You need to show your code; use `seekToBeginning()` rather than seeking to a specific offset.